# Apex read from multiselect SelectList in Controller and multiple for loops

Tags: apex, controller, multi-select, selectlist

I trying to post something to a Facebook page using my own API.The Visualforce Page gets the Facebook Page info and displays a checkbox. The user then selects the Pages and clicks Submit.

Here is my Controller code.

```
public String[] FacebookOptions = new String[]{};

if (postFacebook)
          {

              FACEOFFERS_Settings__c settings = [select Id, MerchantId__c from FACEOFFERS_Settings__c];
              string merchantId = settings.MerchantId__c;

              FaceOffersAppClaim AppClaim = FaceOffersController.GetToken();   

              FaceoffersSocialAccount facebook = GetFaceBookAccount();

              List<FacebookAccountModel> facebookPages = FaceOffersController.GetFacebookPages(merchantId, facebook.AccessToken, AppClaim.Token);

              for (String[] i : facebookOptions)
              {

                  //Get short URL 
                  string shortURL = FaceOffersController.GetShortURLSocialMedia(selectedOfferId); 

                  if(i.getValue() != null)
                  {

                      for (FacebookAccountModel a : facebookPages)
                      {
                          if (i.getValue() == a.id)
                          {
                              FacebookPost post = new FacebookPost(merchantId, a.id, a.access_token, 'A deal on us!', shortURL );

                              FaceOffersController.PostToFacebook(post, AppClaim.Token);
                          }
                      }

                  }
              }

          } 

public String[] getFacebookOptions() {

        return FacebookOptions;

    }

    public void setFacebookOptions(String[] FacebookOptions) {

        this.FacebookOptions = FacebookOptions;
}
```

I can see the Facebook Page Id in FacebookOptions when I debug, but I can't get to it. If I can get to the Id, I can then try to match the Ids in this statement if (i.getValue() == a.id).

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: List doesn't have a method `getValue()`?

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for the reply! I'm stuck. Any idea what I can do to get the Page Id? What about the for loops? Is there a better way to filter lists in Apex?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39241324/5360237

```
for (String pageId : FacebookOptions)
```

The pageId then contains the string values from FacebookOptions.

The first if statement is now this.

```
if(pageId != null)
```

The final if statement looks like this.

```
if (pageId == a.id)
```